# How to reopen Room Database once closed

Tags: android, database, encryption, android-room, android-room-prepackageddatabase

I want to encrypt an existing database of the room.
To do this, I created the database with createFromAsset() method and closed it.
When trying to rebuild the database again after encryption,
contents of database is empty.

```
        String str = "pass";
        char[] pass = str.toCharArray();

        //build
        AppDatabase db = Room.databaseBuilder(getApplicationContext(), AppDatabase.class, "dictionary_word32")
                .createFromAsset("database/dictionary_word14")
                .addMigrations(MIGRATION_1_2)
                .addMigrations(MIGRATION_3_4)
                .addMigrations(MIGRATION_4_5)
                .addMigrations(MIGRATION_5_6)
                .allowMainThreadQueries()
                .build();

        db.close();

        //encryption
        SQLCipherUtils.State state = SQLCipherUtils.getDatabaseState(getApplicationContext(), "dictionary_word31");
        Log.d("TAG", String.valueOf(state));
        if (state == SQLCipherUtils.State.UNENCRYPTED) {
            try {
                SQLCipherUtils.encrypt(getApplicationContext(), "dictionary_word31", pass);
                Log.d("TAG", "Successfully encrypted database!");
            } catch (IOException e) {
                Log.e("TAG", "Failed to encrypt previously unencrypted database!");
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        final byte[] passphrase = SQLiteDatabase.getBytes(pass);
        final SupportFactory factory = new SupportFactory(passphrase);

        //reopen
        db = Room.databaseBuilder(getApplicationContext(), AppDatabase.class, "dictionary_word32")
                .allowMainThreadQueries()
                .openHelperFactory(factory)
                .build();
```

Even if you omit the encryption, the result is the same.

```
        //build
        AppDatabase db = Room.databaseBuilder(getApplicationContext(), AppDatabase.class, "dictionary_word32")
                .createFromAsset("database/dictionary_word14")
                .addMigrations(MIGRATION_1_2)
                .addMigrations(MIGRATION_3_4)
                .addMigrations(MIGRATION_4_5)
                .addMigrations(MIGRATION_5_6)
                .allowMainThreadQueries()
                .build();

        db.close();

        //reopen
        db = Room.databaseBuilder(getApplicationContext(), AppDatabase.class, "dictionary_word32")
                .allowMainThreadQueries()
                .build();
```

Would you tell me how to reopen a database once closed.

Comment: Just don't close it, to begin with.

Comment: I was told by supporter that it had to be closed before trying to encrypt database.

Comment: https://discuss.zetetic.net/t/encrypting-existing-database/4783